# JPA fetch one column twice

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, fetch

I use JPA/Hibernate3 MySql

msyql:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| org_id | org_name | parent_id |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| dept1  | dev      | -1        |
| dept2  | system   | dept1     |
| detp3  | service  | dept2     |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

java

```
String sql = "select "
               + "    t01.org_id,   "
               + "    t01.org_name, "
               + "    t02.org_name as parent_name "
               + "from s_organization t01 left join s_organization t02 "
               + "                               on t01.parent_id = t02.org_id ";  
    List<Object[]> list= em.createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();
    for(Object[] objs : list) {
        System.out.println(String.format("org_name:[%8s] parent_name:[%8s]", 
                objs[1], objs[2]));
    }
```

result：

```
 org_name:[     dev] parent_name:[     dev]
 org_name:[  system] parent_name:[  system]
 org_name:[ service] parent_name:[ service]
```

why `org_name` is equals to `parent_name` ?
how to fix it?

I want show organization in my list page, but data is wrong.

Comment: Can't reproduce this.  I've run the code in this question in Hibernate JPA 4.3.7.  The output is as expected and not like what is described here.

Comment: I used Hibernate3 before, then I try Hibernate4, output is right. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the behavior but can you just try these,

1. Given an alias name for the `org_name`.
2. Remove `String.format`. and first try to print `objs[1]` and `objs[2]` and check what is getting printed.

Comment: It's a bug in Hibernate3, then I try hibernate4 everything is ok